# PySpark - Filtering Selecting based on a condition .groupby

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to use a .groupBy function to find the AVG score based on Position by Country where the country = USA

This is my current code: This code works for displaying every nationality but I just want it to display the avg score based on position for players from the USA only. Any help would be much appreciated.

```py
df.groupby(['Nationality', 'Position])\
    .agg({"Score": "AVG"})\
    .orderBy("Nationality", ascending=True)\
    .show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert the `df.filter(df.Nationality == "USA)` before your groupby.

```
df.filter(df.Nationality == "USA")\
.groupby(['Nationality', 'Position'])\
.agg({"Score": "AVG"})\
.orderBy("Nationality", ascending=True)\
.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. for responding: When I use your code I still get an error: AttributeError: 'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'filter'

Comment: I´m sorry, insert the command before groupby operation, as I've just edited now.